# How to use if statement in jQuery PHP to collect data sent by the user?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to collect the form's data using jQuery after it is submitted by the user. In the form, I automatically send a "country_indicator" variable to the server indicating which language the current user is speaking. Depending on which, the method of choosing the user's nationality is different. But before these data can be sent, I have the code below to check if these data are valid data.

For example, if the person speaks English, "country_indicator" will send "en" and the user will choose his nationality using a select drop-down list; On the other hand, if the person speaks simplified Chinese, "country_indicator" will be "hans" and the user will submit his nationality by tying it into the text box instead of choosing one.

My code which will catch all these info using jQuery looks like below:

```js
jQuery("#contact_submit").bind("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

        var response = {
            country_indicator: jQuery("#country_indicator").val(),
            contact_first_name: jQuery("#contact_first_name").val(),   // required
            contact_last_name: jQuery("#contact_last_name").val(),              // required

            // contact_country: jQuery("#contact_country option:selected").text(),                  // required
            contact_company: jQuery("#contact_company").val(),                  // required
            contact_email: jQuery("#contact_email").val(),   // required
            contact_phone: jQuery("#contact_phone").val(),   // optional
            contact_subject: jQuery("#contact_subject").val(),   // optional
            contact_message: jQuery("#contact_message").val(),   // required
            contact_captcha: jQuery("#contact_captcha").val(),   // required
            agreement_checkbox: jQuery("#agreement_checkbox").is(':checked'),   // spam if checked
            _action: jQuery("#contactForm").attr('action'), // form action URL
            _method: jQuery("#contactForm").attr('method'), // form method
            _err: false        // status
        };

            if(response.country_indicator == "hans" || response.country_indicator == "hant")
            {
                contact_country: jQuery("#contact_country").val(),
            }
            else
            {
                contact_country: jQuery("#contact_country option:selected").text(),
            }

      jQuery("input, textarea, select").removeClass('err');
```

I'm new to js and jQuery, I don't know if I can use if statement like above, please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't server code, this is client side javascript written in jquery!!

Comment: Your response object is also invalid. You have an if/else statement inf your object as if it's a property. Object must be name/value pairs

Comment: @Iceman forgive me being so naive, this code is actually a double check mechanism before sending data to server, you are absolutely right!

Comment: @DawnZHANG no worries. pls remove php tag and re-edit you question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not formatted correctly and probably throwing a bunch of syntax errors. Here is the correct format for what you're trying to do:

```
jQuery("#contact_submit").bind("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var response = {
        country_indicator: jQuery("#country_indicator").val(),
        contact_first_name: jQuery("#contact_first_name").val(),            // required
        contact_last_name: jQuery("#contact_last_name").val(),              // required

        contact_country: jQuery("#contact_country option:selected").text(),                  // required
        contact_company: jQuery("#contact_company").val(),                  // required
        contact_email: jQuery("#contact_email").val(),          // required
        contact_phone: jQuery("#contact_phone").val(),          // optional
        contact_subject: jQuery("#contact_subject").val(),          // optional
        contact_message: jQuery("#contact_message").val(),          // required
        contact_captcha: jQuery("#contact_captcha").val(),          // required
        agreement_checkbox: jQuery("#agreement_checkbox").is(':checked'),   // spam if checked
        _action: jQuery("#contactForm").attr('action'), // form action URL
        _method: jQuery("#contactForm").attr('method'), // form method
        _err: false                             // status
    };

    if(response.country_indicator == "hans" || response.country_indicator == "hant") {
        response.contact_country = jQuery("#contact_country").text();
    }
    else {
        response.contact_country = jQuery("#contact_country option:selected").text();
    }
});
```

Now, as for your issue, as @Iceman said, this is not server side code. This is your client side code (javascript). Uncomment the line `contact_country: jQuery("#contact_country option:selected").text()` and your object should be correct and all you need to do is send it to the server.

Comment: response.contact_country: jQuery("#contact_country").val(); in if statement has a syntax error, it should be response.contact_country=jQuery("#contact_country").val();

Comment: Sorry. It was a quick cut and paste job. Fixed now.